# rank of a C^1 map

Tags: real-analysis

I saw this three star problem in Hirsch ..

If we have open sets $U \subset R^3$ ,$V \subset  R^2$ and $f:U \to V$ is $C^1$  and onto...Prove there is at least one point in $U$ where $f$ has full rank

I want to know the following things

$1)$Is this problem still open?(As three stars problems in Hirsch are supposed to be open)

$2)$If so what relevant progress has been made?